# How to hide <body> without DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks to anyone who solves/helps solving this request. Sorry if this is an impossible/previously asked request. I searched for it, couldn't find it, so posted a question.

So, the issue is, I want to hide  using JS, but, I don't wanna use DIV tags to do so.

```
<body>
<div id="1">Content 1</div>
<div id="2">Content 2</div>
<div id="3">Content 3</div>
</body>
```

I know the possibilty of grouping the DIV's into a single DIV container, but just wanted to know, if it's possible without that, i.e., hiding the whole `<body></body>`

Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.display = "none";
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aq2ab77v/1/

Comment: I asked for JS, not CSS. But thanks for answering anyways.

Comment: I've changed to JS, sorry for the CSS version

Comment: Thanks mate. BTW may I ask, what [0] is for?

Comment: It's because it selects "all" the body tags, but you only have one, so you must put [0]. For example if you would have multiple li's you would do [0] or [1] depending on which one you want to select.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @SaumyaBanthia

Answer (score 4):

### The JavaScript way of accomplishing this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "none";
```

### The jQuery way of accomplishing this:

You will want to select the `body` tag with jquery, and run `.hide()` on it.

```
$('body').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. :D

Comment: @FlorinPop, please see:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251398/594235   In this case, there is nothing original about that single line of JavaScript you could legitimately claim as your original content.  In other words, if this was my answer, I'd include the "JavaScript Way", thereby making this the better answer.

Comment: Quote: "as long as you give attribution." He didn't done that in the first edit. :) And it was exactly the BODY with capital as in my version. I'm sorry but I just want to be a fair guy... I don't copy, so I don't want to be copied without, repeat "giving an attribution"... :)

Comment: @FlorinPop, I want to be fair too... but you cannot own the copyright to `getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]`

Comment: I am not owning it... Who said so? :) I just didn't liked the guy that copied my answer into his answer without giving me an attribution... that's all... At least he could change `getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]` to `getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`

Comment: *facepalm*​​​​​ Let's all be friends.

Comment: @FlorinPop, because copying answers and giving attribution has *everything* to do with copyrights and content ownership.